# Conditional in left join - Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, postgresql

I need to resolve a query that has conditionals inside a join.

Have 3 tables:

companies - TABLE A

```
id - name - type - code
```

tributary_regime_codes - TABLE B

```
id - code_category_id - code
```

tributary_regime_codes_categories - TABLE C

```
id - label - slug
```

I need to make a query so that if the `code` of table B is = '2135' the `code` of table A has the column with the type = 'S'

returning something like (join with table C)

[
{
description: 'Simple',
'companies': 708
},
{
description: 'Simple2',
'companies': 1204
}
]

I have this query atm:

```
$regimes = DB::table('tributary_regime_codes')
        ->join('tributary_regime_codes_categories', 'tributary_regime_codes.code_category_id', '=', 'tributary_regime_codes_categories.id')
        ->select([
            'tributary_regime_codes_categories.label',
            'tributary_regime_codes_categories.slug',
            DB::raw('sum(totalCompanies) as quantity'),
        ])->leftJoinSub($companiesRegimeCodes, 'companies', function ($join) {
            $join->on('tributary_regime_codes.code', '=', 'companies.code');
        })->groupBy([
            'tributary_regime_codes_categories.label',
            'tributary_regime_codes_categories.slug'
        ]);
```

Comment: Afraid I don't understand the question, you mention only one exception but what happens for all other situations?  also: What happens if in your data companies.type <> 'S' ?   is this just a filter condition? and if so, then should it just be in the where clause? (which also then suggests you don't need a left join)

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but does have certain expectations you need to satisfy. Spend a few minutes to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to review [ask]. Please post actual table definitions (ddl) and sample data for each table, all as text - **no images**. Additionally post the exact results expected from that data. saying results *something like ...* is  just **not satisfactory**.